# Find delta angle to use for rotation given entity with position, initial rotation and target point to 'face toward'

Tags: java, math, vector, rotation, ardor3d

I'm coding a flocking algorithm in Java but I'm stuck at a certain point (using the Ardor3D libraries, in a 2D plane).

Basically, I need to find the angle difference to add to the current rotation. If you can only get the way it should be pointing with polar coordinates with 0 degs at north and not the difference, not to worry -- I have a method which returns the angle difference taking into account the wraparound on the angle and negative angles.

[image]

At the moment, I have the following code, which clearly wouldn't work since the algorithm has no reference to the initial rotation:

```
  long tpf = currUpdateTimeMS - lastUpdateTimeMS;

  Vector2 pos = new Vector2();
  rt.getPosition(pos);

  double rot = pos.angleBetween(app.getAvgBoidPos(new Vector2()).normalizeLocal());
  rt.setRotation(rot);

  pos.addLocal(
   Math.cos((rot - MathUtils.HALF_PI)) * (tpf / 10f),
   Math.sin((rot - MathUtils.HALF_PI)) * (tpf / 10f)
  );
  rt.setPosition(pos);

  super.updateLogic();
```

Updated code (not working, from first answer):

```
    long tpf = currUpdateTimeMS - lastUpdateTimeMS;
    //rt.setRotation(rt.getRotation() + ((tpf / (ROT_SPEED / 2f)) % 360));

    Vector2 avgpos = app.getAvgBoidPos(new Vector2());
    Vector2 pos = rt.getPosition(new Vector2());
    avgpos.subtractLocal(pos);

    double angleRads = rt.getRotation() * FastMath.DEG_TO_RAD;
    double rot = MathUtils.acos((
        (avgpos.getX() * MathUtils.sin(angleRads)
    ) +
        (avgpos.getY() * MathUtils.cos(angleRads)
    )) / ((Math.pow(avgpos.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(avgpos.getY(), 2)) * 0.5));

    double adegdiff = rot * FastMath.RAD_TO_DEG;

    rt.setRotation(rt.getRotation() - adegdiff);
    double newrot = rt.getRotation();

    pos.addLocal(
        Math.cos((newrot - MathUtils.HALF_PI)) * (tpf / 10f),
        Math.sin((newrot - MathUtils.HALF_PI)) * (tpf / 10f)
    );
    rt.setPosition(pos);

    super.updateLogic();
```

Another modification based on the other answer:

```
    long tpf = currUpdateTimeMS - lastUpdateTimeMS;
    //rt.setRotation(rt.getRotation() + ((tpf / (ROT_SPEED / 2f)) % 360));

    Vector2 avgpos = app.getAvgBoidPos(new Vector2());
    Vector2 pos = rt.getPosition(new Vector2());
    avgpos.subtractLocal(pos);

    double rot = pos.angleBetween(
        app.getAvgBoidPos(new Vector2()).normalizeLocal()
    ) - (rt.getRotation() * MathUtils.DEG_TO_RAD);

    rt.setRotation(rt.getRotation() - (rot * MathUtils.RAD_TO_DEG));
    double newrot = rt.getRotation();

    pos.addLocal(
        Math.cos((newrot - MathUtils.HALF_PI)) * (tpf / 10f),
        Math.sin((newrot - MathUtils.HALF_PI)) * (tpf / 10f)
    );
    rt.setPosition(pos);

    super.updateLogic();
```

I'm not really too good at Maths problems, so code would be helpful rather than formulas :)

Inputs

- Current position of entity
- Current rotation of entity (polar-oriented) in degrees

Output

- Degrees or radians to add or subtract to current rotation
- ... or degrees or radians expressed as polar-oriented angle

Thanks in advance if you can help :)

Chris

Comment: So `rt.getPosition` gives the position of the entity and `app.getAvgBOIDPos` gives the target position, is that right? And what gives the orientation of the entity?

Comment: That'd be rt.getRotation(), which is expressed in polar-oriented degrees :)

Comment: Oops, forgot to say that you're right about app,getAvgBoidPos() giving the average location of entities for the entity to move towards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dot product to determine the cosine of the angle (in radians) between the current orientation and the point you want to face.  Assume the agent doing the viewing is locate at the origin and oriented to face some direction given by the angle θ relative to the Y-Axis (i.e. 0 degrees is "up" or "north").  You want to find the angular difference θ' between that direction and facing a point (x, y).  That is given by:

```
θ' = cos-1[(x*sin(θ) + y*cos(θ)) / sqrt(x2 + y2)]
```

Subtracting θ' from θ will orient the agent towards the target.

If the agent is not at the origin, simply subtract the position of the agent from the object to view to bring it into the form above.

Comment: Got it. I'll try implementing this and come back to you if there's any problem :)

Comment: I implemented it, but it doesn't seem to be working. I think the x and y elements of position are getting NaN due to division by zero somewhere? Anyway, I updated the question with the new code :)

Comment: @Chris Dennett: I think I tried to be too clever for my own good. You multiplied the denominator by 1/2. I was trying to express it as raising it to the power of 1/2 which is the square root. For some values of x and y this could result in the quotient not being in the range of [-1, 1] which will result in NaN when you take the acos of it. I've updated my equation to better show this.

Comment: I got this sorted, turned out to be something quite simple with the angle difference function I was using. but this post gets the answer mark for being the closest to the implemented solution :)

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: How to calculate `θ` if I only have the source location, the current orientation and the target location?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic, but you might find the particle swarm and wander code in our effects package (ardor3d-effects) interesting as well.

They can be found in the ardor svn, or here:

http://ardorlabs.trac.cvsdude.com/Ardor3Dv1/browser/trunk/ardor3d-effects/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/extension/effect/particle/

Comment: By the way, it's not exactly off-topic as the thing I wanted to implement is swarming anyway :) The 'finding average position' element is a part of that, and I got it working. But there are other elements to the problem as well, which seem to have been sorted out here :)

Comment: The only problem is that the particle code doesn't have rotation and speed which I could do with -- it only has velocity in x, y and z. But it shouldn't be that hard to convert between them. If I make the speed a product of the rotation and velocity (I already have the formulas), it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

heres an implementation on how to find the angle beetween two vectors with a common origin. this has been hacked together based on the algorithm described there:
http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors

```
public class DeltaDoodle {

    private double delta(ColumnVector v1,ColumnVector v2) throws Exception{
        double sp=scalarProduct(v1,v2);
        double magV1=magnitude(v1);
        double magV2=magnitude(v2);
        return Math.acos(sp/(magV1*magV2)) * (180/Math.PI);
    }

    private double scalarProduct(ColumnVector a, ColumnVector b) {
        return (a.x*b.x) + (a.y*b.y);
    }
    private double magnitude(ColumnVector a){
        return Math.sqrt((a.x*a.x) + (a.y*a.y));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeltaDoodle v=new DeltaDoodle();
        try {
            System.out.println("angle: " + v.delta(new ColumnVector(5, 5), new ColumnVector(1,1)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class ColumnVector {
    public final double x, y;

    public ColumnVector(double x1, double x2) {
        this.x = x1;
        this.y = x2;
    }
}
```

hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand these functions correctly, this might just work:

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(); 
rt.getPosition(pos); 

double rot = pos.angleBetween(app.getAvgBoidPos(new Vector2()).normalizeLocal()) - rt.getRotation();
```

P.S. Forgot to mention: this `rot` is intended to be the angle difference. Rotate the entity by this much and it should be pointing toward the target.

**EDIT:**
Thanks, the code does help (I had misconstrued `angleBetween`). Let me try again:

Here is the vector from the entity to the point (pardon me if I get the syntax wrong, I don't know java):

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(); 
rt.getPosition(pos); 

Vector2 direction = app.getAvgBoidPos(new Vector2());
direction.subtractLocal(pos);
```

Now we normalize it to get a unit vector pointing toward the point, and take the angle difference:

```
double rot = rt.getRotation().angleBetween(direction.normalizeLocal())
```

Comment: Not working :/ Here is the Vector2 source code if it helps: http://ardorlabs.trac.cvsdude.com/Ardor3Dv1/browser/trunk/ardor3d-core/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/math/Vector2.java?rev=152